# Creating html sliders that change oppositely to an user controlled slider

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I am trying to create a group of sliders that respond to changes in any slider. So if one moves left by one, I want the others to move right by one and so on. This is what I have so far:

```
//to track values of the ranges
var currVals = {}
```

I created a function for adjusting range

```
function adjustRange(changing){
    //iterate thru all range inputs
    let ranges =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
    //find the change -> inc or dec
    let delta = parseInt(changing.value) - parseInt(currVals[changing.id]);
    ranges.forEach((range) => {
        let prev = currVals[range.id];
        if (range.id === changing.id){
            //update currVal
            currVals[range.id] =  parseInt(range.value);
        }
        else {
            // set values of the other sliders
            range.setAttribute('value', parseInt(prev) - delta);
            //update currVal
            currVals[range.id] =  parseInt(prev) - delta;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
    const MAXUNITS = 100;
    var prevVal = {};
    //
    function adjustRange(input, e, size){
    let curr = parseInt(e.target.value);
    let delta = parseInt(prevVal[input.id]) - curr;
    //iterate thru all range inputs
    console.log('currently changing: ', curr);
    let ranges =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
    ranges.forEach((range) => {
        if (range.id !== input.id){
            range.value = parseInt(range.value) + (delta)/(size - 1);
        }
        prevVal[range.id] = range.value;
    });
}
```

Yes I know, some of the variables are redundant